# What's this code supposed to do? (reference to rvalue)

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I have read that the code below is valid in C++11:

```
int && a = 3;
a = 4;
```

Is it supposed to write 4 in the memory address where the numeric literal 3 is stored? Maybe some compiler optimizations would prevent this from happening, but is it supposed to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign a prvalue that is not of class type to an rvalue reference, a temporary object is created and the reference is bound to that. You are simply modifying the temporary object.

> A reference to type “cv1 `T1`” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 `T2`” as follows:
>
> - If the reference is an lvalue reference [...]
> - Otherwise, [...] or **the reference shall be an rvalue reference**.
>
>   - If the initializer expression
>
>     - is an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue [...], or
>     - has a class type [...]
>
>     [...]
>   - **Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1 `T1`” is created** and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the temporary.

Conceptually, a prvalue is just a value that may or may not have come from some object in memory. Literals don't have a corresponding object in memory, so this rule forces an object to be created.

Comment: You and I were just looking at this the other day. :) Nice coincidence.